# After Rails 4 upgrade session info cutoff

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I recently upgraded an app from rails 3.2 to rails 4. I'm having an issue with exception emails, mostly around the session info no longer gives a full detail

Rails 3.2:

```
-------------------------------
Session:
-------------------------------

  * session id: [FILTERED]
  * data: {"session_id"=>"f95f527ce9b8829396863e755adf4087",
   "_csrf_token"=>"Gr4dGdPtoEPN/1gQ4mzzqpTv45D9vErwIuc28Z/q2Ww=",
   "user_credentials"=>
    "0a1ed7c0e02c01c01c11a1d7f997029d644f97dfdcad5a891b89674313eb439b89bc17b2e97236a50c1e5e1533a9ad99b650883daeb8ad9163dd049f3f78ec28",
   "user_credentials_id"=>104,
   "return_to"=>"/home/index",
   "two_pair"=>false}
```

Rails 4:

```
-------------------------------
Session:
-------------------------------

  * session id: [FILTERED]
  * data: #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007ff634e5df80 ...>
```

How can I get the data to be drilled out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `inspect` or `to_json`

```
# This is your data
# data: #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007ff634e5df80 ...>

data.inspect  # Lays it all out there for you
data.to_json  # Puts it in json format

# You can also try YAML
data.to_yaml  # In YAML format, very easy to read
```

View the [Handy-dandy Rails Debugging Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) for more tips.

Comment: Where can i specify this in my rails app?

Comment: Is this being printed from a test, an error log, in the console, or where?

Comment: I was using a gem and needed to upgrade it, but this helps a lot thanks!